# ReactJS Hooks. TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback

I am new to reactJS, I am trying to develop a weather app using React Hooks. The useEffect hook runs infinitely, even the dependency is the same as before. So I decide to use useCallBack hook, However it shows an error.

Code as below:

```
import React,{useState,useEffect,useCallBack} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const WeatherApp = () =>{
  const [weatherData,setWeatherData] = useState({
    latitude:1,
    longitude:0,
    city:'',
    country:'',
    description:'',
    temperature:'',
    apiKey:"96f70a610a2b066259b75fc8d23eab98",
    icon:''
  });

  const getWeatherByCoords = useCallBack(()=>{
    let api=`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${weatherData.latitude}&lon=${weatherData.longitude}&appid=${weatherData.apiKey}`;

    axios.get(api)
      .then(res=>{
        const data = res.data;
        setWeatherData(pre=>({...pre,
          country:data.sys.country,
          city:data.name,
          temperature:data.main.temp,
          description:data.weather[0].description
        }));
        console.log(weatherData);

      })
      .catch(error=>errorHandler(error));
  },[weatherData]);


  const errorHandler = error=>{
    console.log(error);
  }
 useEffect(()=>{
   // const interval = setInterval(()=>{
     if(navigator.geolocation){
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position=>{
       setWeatherData({...weatherData,
         latitude:position.coords.latitude,
         longitude:position.coords.longitude});
       getWeatherByCoords();
     },error=>errorHandler(error),{timeout:10000});
   }
 // },1000);
   // return(()=> clearInterval(interval));
},[getWeatherByCoords]);

  // fetch(`api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${key}`)

  return(
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>City</h1>
        <h2>Date</h2>
        <h3>Description</h3>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img alt='This is an img'></img>
        <h2>Temperature</h2>
        <p> <span>°C</span>|<span>°F</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};

export default WeatherApp;
```

Error:[image]

If I use useMemo, the error will become: getWeatherByCoords is not a function. I am very confused. I have spend whole day on this. Thanks a lot if anyone can help.

Comment: typo: `useCallBack` -> `useCallback`

Comment: Thank a lot.  That's so a stupid mistake.   It works now.  The useEffect hook still runs all the time. Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: I think you should remove the dependency `getWeatherByCoords` in `useEffect`, just leave it an empty array: `[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useEffect` and `useCallback` will run whenever the dependency changes.

So if your dependency is the one that is going to be changed inside the hook, it will trigger a loop.

You dont' need `useCallback` in your case.

Just trigger axios API method inside the `useEffect` and then setting the state of `weatherData` without any dependency will do.

Comment: Thanks, however, if I remove the dependency the weatherDate will never be updated. It is the initial state all the time.

Comment: how about without the dependency array.  like useEffect(() => { ...do your api calling here }); dont' console.log(weatherData); because react will prompt you to add weatherData as dependency. if you want to see if it works, just { JSON.stringify(weatherData) } in the JSX . if it's working , remove the tested string.